# textedit file delete after restart on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, textedit

#### Situation

I got textedit file, which was already saved, but not closed, opened while I was restarting Mac OS X system.

#### The problem

After restart the file was not there in folder and I was unable to find it.

Is there any option how to restore the file or somehow get the data back?

#### Possible solutions

I could try to search text in all files on the hard drive to match some file maybe like this:

```
grep -l  [text to find] [files to look in]
```

I could try to restore some data using deleted files recovery program like stated on [Cult of Mac](http://www.cultofmac.com/67472/how-to-undelete-files-in-mac-os-x-macrx/).

Any of these seem not to work for me. I hope someone knows some other solutions.